# How Does Solidity Constructor Syntax Work?

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts

I'm having trouble understanding the syntax of the following line of Solidity used to construct an ERC20 token using the OpenZepplin library:

```
constructor(uint256 cap) ERC20("DevToken", "DVT") ERC20Capped(cap){ }
```

I'm looking for clarification of the following points:

- Why does the constructor seemingly have two names; 'ERC20' and 'ERC20Capped'?
- Why does the ERC20Capped portion take a 'cap' variable instead of actual data like the ERC20 portion does?

If someone is able to go through word by word and explain the entire line that would be even more helpful.

I find the documentation for solidity very hard to understand, as an aside, does anyone have any recommendations for resources that will help me better understand the syntax of the language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - constructor does not have any names. `constructor` of the contract is only called when you deploy the contract

Your base contract is inheriting from two other contracts:

```
ERC20("DevToken", "DVT") ERC20Capped(cap)
```

when a contract inherits from another contract, it gains access to the inherited contract's functions, variables, and modifiers. During deployment, the bytecode of the base contract includes the bytecode of the inherited contracts. This creates a single bytecode file that represents the complete functionality of the deploying contract and its inherited contracts. since inherited contracts have `constructor` function, when you deploy your contract, you are initializing those constructors, as well.

> - Why does the ERC20Capped portion take a 'cap' variable instead of actual data like the ERC20 portion does?

you should check inherited contracts and they will tell you what parameters are passed to their constructors

Comment: So is this line of code is calling each of the constructors it inherits individually? Does it matter what order they are written in?

Comment: it calls sequentially. it does matter. first constructor, then `ERC20("DevToken", "DVT")` and then ERC20Capped(cap)

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't aware multiple functions could be called in one line. Why is it done this way instead of inside the constructor class? Also, Why wouldn't ERC20Capped take "DevToken" and "DVT" as parameters and call the ERC20 constructor, passing those variables? Wouldn't this remove the need to have to explicitly call the ERC20 constructor ourselves?

Comment: As @Yilmaz you actually *are* calling the constructors, in the specified order. And for your 2nd part of the question, that depends on the implementation detail of `ERC20Capped`. I'd suggest taking a look at its source code and docs to see what it really does, and therefore how it expects to be invoked. What you're really asking here is about the design decisions of the whoever implemented `ERC20Capped` (and not really about how Solidity the language/ compiler is designed to work)